# Getting error on trying to print shapes with for loop

Tags: java

So basically my teacher wants us to print each shape that is in my ArrayList using this method

```
for (Shape shape: shapes) {
    // this following is the same as: System.out.println(shape.toString());
    System.out.println(shape);
}
```

Which she does not clear up at all so I have no idea what I am supposed to fill in. If anyone knows what she is trying to explain can you show me an example?

I'm not asking to write the code for me just asking for an example so I can get the idea of it.

Thank you for your time everyone.

**Full Code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FinalExam {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

        Circle circle5 = new Circle();
        circle5.setValues(5.0);

        Rectangle square5 = new Rectangle();
        square5.setValues(5.0, 5.0);

        Triangle triangle5 = new Triangle();
        triangle5.setValues(5.0, 5.0);

        Circle circle3 = new Circle();
        circle3.setValues(3.0);

        Rectangle square3 = new Rectangle();
        square3.setValues(3.0, 3.0);

        Triangle triangle3 = new Triangle();
        triangle3.setValues(3.0, 3.0);

        shapes.add(circle5);
        shapes.add(square5);
        shapes.add(triangle5);
        shapes.add(circle3);
        shapes.add(square3);
        shapes.add(triangle3);
    }

    public void  printShapes() {
        for (Circle element: Circle) {
            // this following is the same as: System.out.println(shape.toString());
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

**Circle class**

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
    private double Radius;  // To hold Radius.

    // Set Radius
    public void setValues(double Radius) {
        this.Radius = Radius;
    }

    //Get Radius
    public double getRadius() {
        return Radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return (Math.PI * Radius *Radius);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Circle" +"[Radius:" + getRadius() + "] Area:" + String.format("%.02f", getArea());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say your teach is waiting for you to override `toString()` in your `Shape`objects ;) But it's juste a guess though.

Comment: Well, what does your teacher expect should be printed for each shape?  Don't you think this is the real question here?

Comment: already did that thats why i am confused there

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i think she wants us to pring the area for each shape that is why i am confused by the code she is trying to get us to create

Comment: Can we see the definitions for the shapes classes?  Don't show us the full code, that's too much information.  Just the fields each class has, and the getters/setters.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  i added the code for circle class the rectangle and triangle are basically the same with just a few changes

Comment: Your code looks reasonable.  What is the problem then?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  It says i have an error with the word after the Colon in the for loop idk what goes there

Comment: You need to pass `shapes` and print it using `for (Shape shape: shapes)`

Comment: Also program to interface and use `List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a corrected version of your `FinalExam` class:

```
public class FinalExam {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

        // define and add shapes here

        printShapes(shapes);
    }

    public static void printShapes(List<Shape> list) {
        for (Shape shape : list) {
            System.out.println(shape);
        }
    }
}
```

Your syntax to iterate was incorrect, and also I think both methods should be `static` (assuming `main` is static, and you want to use it).  In the above version, I pass the list of shapes to the printing method, but you could also handle this in other ways.